# Refresh eclipse project classpath

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am using eclipse and gradle 3

For x.1 release performed the project build externally from command prompt :

gradlew.bat

It downloaded some dependencies and saved in user.home.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1

I have other project say x.2 performed same steps here as well. but in this release have some newer dependencies.

So when i open x.1 project i can see older dependencies are deleted. again i fired the command for project x.1 to download the dependencies.
Now how i can tell eclipse to refresh its class path?

i can see error saying missing required library.
I can see difference in jars location.

e.g. previous location for common-cli

.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\1303efbc4b181e5a58bf2e967dc156a3132b97c0

New location ( Again firing the gradle build) for commons-cli

.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\dsdsfdsfffdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdfdfdfdfdfdffd

Any way to tell eclipse to refresh it's classpath?

Comment: Use gradle Eclipse plugin and regenrate classpath with `./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` on command line

Comment: How was it set originally?